# Outbound message on merging records

Tags: salesforce

When I merge accounts, I want to trigger an outbound message. When I merge account, there is 1 record that is updated and and the other record that goes to recycle bin. I want to fetch Record Id of one that is merged with and the one that is updated. Is it possible with any conditions or do i need to code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you need to write a trigger for this although a rather simple one.
As stated in documentation merge doesn't trigger they own event instead delete and uppate events triggered.
From Documentation :

*To determine which records were deleted as a result of a merge operation use the
MasterRecordId field in Trigger.old. When a record is deleted after losing a merge 
operation, its MasterRecordId field is set to the ID of the winning record.*

[Link to full page](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_triggers_merge_statements.htm)

Comment: Hi @Moti Korets, I wrote a trigger that will get the record id of the loser and update in the winner record. But when I merge 3 records I am not able to get two loser id's. I dont know where I am going wrong.

Comment: If its another issue maybe its better ask a new question with the relevant code posted.